# sed replace multiple matches per line

Tags: sed, html

I am trying to replace some html links such that they open in a new tab (Except links that point to the same page).

Here is a dummy html page to illustrate my issue. I call it **test.html**.

```
<p>
This is the <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google link</a>
</p>

<p>
And these are <a href="https://twitter.com/">Twitter link</a> and <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">Instagram link</a>.
</p>
```

I am using this code to find and replace links with some addition.

```
sed -E 's/(<a href="[^#]+[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=/?&]+")(>)/\1 target="_blank">/g' test.html
```

The result looks like this:

```
<p>
This is the <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google link</a>
</p>

<p>
And these are <a href="https://twitter.com/">Twitter link</a> and <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">Instagram link</a>.
</p>
```

Note the addition of `target="_blank"`. It works as expected, except when there are multiple matches. In case of multiple matches per line, only the rightmost one is replaced. It seems to be detecting the whole line as a block.

Looking into this a bit, I found a suggestion to add a negation to split the detection blocks. So I added a negation for closing tag `>` like `^>` so the code looks like

```
sed -E 's/(<a href="[^#]+[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=/?&^>]+")(>)/\1 target="_blank">/g' test.html
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything. Perhaps, I am doing this wrong.

Running/testing now on **sed 4.7**. Intended to be run on **sed 4.4**.

Comment: Do not use `sed` to edit `html`. Better to use some proper `html` parser, e.g. `python`'s `BeautifulSoup` module.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is not a robust solution. It's just intended as a quick temporary fix while something more complex is being worked on.

Comment: I love the optimism of believing that a quick-and-dirty fix will actually get replaced with a robust, correct solution any time before the Q&D hack breaks (which will almost certainly be at the worst possible moment, in the worst possible way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `[^#]+` matches everything from the first href to the end of the second. If you want to avoid only links starting with `#`, remove the `+`.